# Visual Basic: conteo de letras repetidas

Tags: vb.net

Nesecito un programa en donde el usuario agrege una cadena, me cuente las letras y me diga en un `label`, cuantas letras estan repetidas usando visual basic.

Por ejemplo:

> Hola helena
>
> H(2),o(1),l(2),a(2),e(2).

Tengo esto:

```
    public string contar()
    {
       string cadena, cadAux = "";
        cadena = getCadenaFrase();
        bool bandera = false;
       
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getCadenaFrase().Length; i++)
        {
            bandera = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (Scf[j] == this.getCadenaFrase().Substring(i, 1))
                {
                    bandera = true;
                }
                if (!bandera && Scf[j] == "")
                {
                    Scf[j] = this.getCadenaFrase().Substring(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
                if (bandera)
                {
                    cadAux = cadAux + " " + j;
                }

                letras[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        return cadAux;
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes probar a crear un diccionario y utilizar las letras como clave y el numero como valor.
El resultado con los totales simplemente serán las claves con sus valores.

**VB**

```
    Dim cad As String = "Hola Helena"
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To cad.Length - 1
        If d.ContainsKey(cad.Substring(i, 1)) Then
            d.Item(cad.Substring(i, 1)) += 1
        Else()
            d.Add(cad.Substring(i, 1), 1)
        End If
    Next
```

**C#**

```
        String cad = textBox1.Text;
        Dictionary<String, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for(int n = 0;n<cad.Length;n++){
            if(d.ContainsKey(cad.Substring(n,1)){
                d[cad.Substring(n,1)]+=1;
            }
            else{
                d.Add(cad.Substring(n,1),1);
            }
        }
```